# Apply feature importance obtained from entire dataset to individual row

Tags: feature-selection

There are various methods for calculating feature importance. These are generally obtained from computing the entire dataset. Can this feature importance be then applied to specific rows?

In other words, what is a practical way of applying feature importance to a specific row? An application is as follows. Say we have a binary classification problem with 10 features, X1, X2, ...., X10. Also, from the feature importance analysis, X1 is more important than X2, X2 is more important than X3, and so on and so forth. Also assumed is that these are numerical features and range between 0 and 5.

Upon the binary prediction, if the prediction is negative, we have one chance to pick a feature and try to influence this feature so that it can yield a positive outcome. Since we can pick only one feature to influence, the feature importance ranking is important.

How do we apply the previously determined feature ranking (from the entire dataset) to this individual?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/slundberg/shap? First example show to apply the feature importance row-wise, to see what extent each row contribute to the target, and not just the aggregate importance for the entire dataset.

Comment: Yes, I have seen SHAP. It is good stuff. SHAP has a very high computing complexity. I am wondering if one can use the feature importance from, say, XGBoost, as a basis and apply it to explain each row.